# Chromium on Raspberry Pi B w/ Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 1, and I would like to install Chromium for my cloud print server. The only trouble is that `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` does not work. Additionally, I tried a method for installing Chromium on RPI, but it was for RPI2 only. I am a noob, and I was wondering whether it is possible to get Chromium on Raspbian Jessie on Raspberry Pi 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium can now be downloaded and installed (with `sudo apt install chromium-browser`) , and now comes preinstalled on the PIXEL desktop environment, but it does struggle to load pages on the small power of earlier Raspberry Pi models, however the model 4B (and to some extent the 3B+ and 3B) can load pages much faster.

Comment: I would like to note that Chromium in some instances will also be run as root, while your user is not a sudo user. But from my experience, I can tell you that you are going to have a bad time running chromium.